# How to convert WebResponse.GetResponseStream return into a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, httpwebresponse

I see many examples but all of them read them into byte arrays or 256 chars at a time, slowly. Why?

Is it not advisable to just convert the resulting `Stream` value into a string where I can parse it?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should create a `StreamReader` around the stream, then call `ReadToEnd`.

You should consider calling `WebClient.DownloadString` instead.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, checking DownloadString now. Actually I am gettng different source code strings compared to my old app where it uses browser.DocumentStream using Winforms Browser control. You think DownloadString would fix it? I can create a new question if it's not as straightforward.

Comment: You either have a encoding issue or you need to set a `User-Agent`.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, I use DownloadString now, and it's better you are right. Now the result differs slightly, shouldn't make a difference but I get stuff like `<a href=` instead of the old one which was `<A href=`. That's still related to encoding or `User-Agent` you think?

Comment: That sounds weird; it might be normalized by IE.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, I noticed IE, chrome, FF all gives slightly different results. So DownloadString still uses IE behind the scenes? Or is it more back more direct no-IE dependent method?

Comment: `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest` use raw HTTP with no browser involved.  If different browsers show different **View Source** s, it's a `User-Agent` issue.

Comment: The answer is valid but comment about WebClient is not. You get WebResponse also from WebException.Response where you get the complete response from remote server..

Answer (score 151):

You can use `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`,

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
   String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: @FaizanMubasher - I'd like to suggest the LINQ To XML.

Comment: Great that you pointed out `StreamReader` takes second parameter `Encoding.UTF8`. Didn't notice that at first while looking at MS documentation

Comment: Shouldn't the encoding be based on the value of response.CharacterSet rather than assuming a fixed value of UTF8?

Comment: LINQ To XML sample?

Comment: `GetResponse and GetResponseStream` can throw ***exceptions***

Answer (score 14):

As @Heinzi mentioned the character set of the response should be used.

```
var encoding = response.CharacterSet == ""
    ? Encoding.UTF8
    : Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
    var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. One bug though, change response.CharacterSet == "" to string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.CharacterSet)

Answer (score 5):

Richard Schneider is right.
use code below to fetch data from site which is not utf8 charset will get wrong string.

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
   String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

"
i can't vote.so wrote this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `StreamReader` around the stream, then call `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`.

```
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
var responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```