# How my .NET controller can correctly return a JSON to the client (obtained by an external REST call)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-apicontroller

I am pretty new in **.NET*** (I came from Java) and I have the following problem.

I created this controller class calling an external REST endpoint (it works fine):

```
namespace MyPrj.Controllers
{

    public class MailProtocolloController : ApiController
    {

        private String urlBaseProtocolloApi = "http://myserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8081/MY_API";

        [SharePointContextWebAPIFilter]
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("GetAooList")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAooList()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INTO GetAooList()");

            string jsonRequest = urlBaseProtocolloApi + "/api/ProtocollaMail/GetDepartmentsList";

            NetworkCredential myCreds = new NetworkCredential("myname", "mypswd", "mydomain");

            CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();

            credCache.Add(new Uri(jsonRequest), "NTLM", myCreds);

            //credCache.Add(new Uri(jsonRequest), "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);

            HttpWebRequest spRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(jsonRequest);
            spRequest.Credentials = credCache;
            spRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.01;+Windows+NT+5.0";
            spRequest.Method = "GET";
            spRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";

            HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)spRequest.GetResponse();

            //string sResult = "Pippo";

            string sResult = endpointResponse.ToString();

            /*
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(endpointResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                sResult = sr.ReadToEnd();

                JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(sResult);
            }
            */

            Console.WriteLine(sResult);

            return Ok(sResult);

        }

    }
}
```

The called REST endpoint (I renamed it for privacy) return a JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name":"Protocollo Generale",
        "Value":"PG"
    }
]
```

My controller have to return this JSON to the client. I tried to do in this way:

```
string sResult = endpointResponse.ToString();
return Ok(sResult);
```

but it is not what I need because it returns:

```
<string>System.Net.HttpWebResponse</string>
```

instead the desired JSON.

What is the correct way to return this JSON to the client? How can I fix it?

Comment: `endpointResponse.ToString()` does not return useful information.  You need to read the response.

Comment: Why did you use HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient? You could have used `var response=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(thatURL);` and retrieve the response. HttpClient won't block either

Comment: @SLaks ehhhh how?

Comment: You want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543324/how-to-convert-webresponse-getresponsestream-return-into-a-string) but as Panagiotis suggests, you should move to `HttpClient`, it's been the default way to do this sort of thing for a long time now.

Comment: The client can define if it wants xml or json just by setting `content-type=application/json`